# What is the relationship between BigOh and growth rate?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o, graph-algorithm

What is the relationship between BigOh and growth rate? Is the growth rate a feature of BigOh function 'O' ?

Answer (score 3):

BigOh just says, growth rate can not be greater than constant factor of growth rate of specific function, It can't show what is growth rate.

**Update**

Assume f(n) = 2*f(n-1) + 1 and f(1) = 1, means f(n) = 2<sup>n</sup> - 1, BigOh for this function can be:

BigOh (f(n)) belongs to { 2<sup>n</sup>, 2<sup>n-100</sup>, 2<sup>2*n</sup>, 2<sup>2<sup>n</sup></sup>, ...} but does not belong to {2<sup>n/2</sup>, n<sup>2</sup>, ....}

As you can see functions like 2<sup>2<sup>n</sup></sup> has very very fast growing rate, but it shows BigOh for 2<sup>n</sup>.

Some functions are incredible, and no one find exact speed of them, one of a best usages of BigOh is in this situations.

In fact when you can't determine θ It's good to find good BigOh, to frankly say my function (algorithm) is not slower than this function. So BigOh is valuable but again may be is very far from your function grows rate. BigOh is good for randomize algorithms also for deterministic complicated functions.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, 'O' *is* the growth rate.

Answer (score -1):

Formally, the relationship between BigOh and growth rate is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition